# terminator not starting when default python is python3.4 but works if it is python2.7

Tags: 15.10, python3, python-2.7, terminator

On Ubuntu 15.10 when changing the symlink /usr/bin/python from python2.7 to python3.4 then terminator won t start anymore.
Do you know what the problem could be and how to fix it?
Thank you :)

Comment: Check `terminator`'s requirements - it may need python 2, and not python 3 - by changing where 'python' links to you forced it to try and use Python 3, where it may not work.

Comment: Check `terminator`'s requirements - it may need python 2, and not python 3 - by changing where 'python' links to you forced it to try and use Python 3, where it may not work.

Comment: Changing `/usr/bin/python`  is just going to cause problems. Don't. Even Python doesn't recommend it:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Comment: Make sure not to have installed it via pip ```pip uninstall terminator``` and reboot the system. `New version` of `terminator` works great with `python3`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply fix it by editing `/usr/bin/terminator` shebang path back to python2, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1621156

Answer (score 5):

Edit the `/usr/bin/terminator`

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/terminator
```

and change the first line (shebang)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

**NOTE:** Get the path of python2 using:

```
$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

Comment: I changed this but it still didn't work. Do I want to build terminator again?

Comment: Just this change should work. Also, please check the path with `which python2` or `which python2.7`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to change the python3 version (I had 3.9 and changed to 3.8). Try to change it directly in the first line of /usr/bin/terminator, from

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

to ex 3.8

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

if this doesn't work try unlink python3 from 3.9 and link to 3.8 and then reinstall terminator:

use `python3 -V` too see immediatly which version you have to see if it is 3.9

1)goto usr/bin: `cd /usr/bin`

2)check each python command what is linked to: `ls -lrth python*`. Here I had `python3 -> python3.9`

also `which python3` should give `/usr/bin/python3`

3)Unlink python3: `sudo unlink python3`

4)Link to another version: `sudo ln -s python3.8 python3`  I had 3.8 but I guess other older version work too. n.b you can use this command to change also python and python2 links

Now `python3 -V` should give the new version

5)Uninstall terminator and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove terminator
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove terminator
sudo apt install terminator
```

Now it should work. if you need python3 to be pyton3.9 you can edit /usr/bin/terminator and change #!/usr/bin/python3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.8 and then relink python3 to python3.9