# How to fix terminator not starting anymore?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, terminator

I am running `terminator` as my main terminal. The only change on my system that I remember was running

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
```

which ran fine. Yet terminator won't start anymore:

```
$ terminator 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I tried purging it:

```
sudo apt purge -y terminator && \
sudo apt install -y terminator
```

Yet the issues prevails. How to make terminator start again?

Furthermore, the version of terminator does not appear to have been changed:

The version of terminator did not appear to change:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep terminator
Commandline: apt purge terminator
Purge: terminator:amd64 (0.98-1)
Commandline: apt install terminator
Install: terminator:amd64 (0.98-1)
Commandline: apt purge terminator
Purge: terminator:amd64 (0.98-1)
```

Comment: You may want to report a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+filebug).

Comment: Also, see if the `dist-upgrade` upgraded `terminator`. Look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. If so, you may be able to downgrade.

Comment: @Jos It appears I always had terminator 0.98-1 all along.

Answer (score 16):

Check your Python default version with:

```
python -V
```

Terminator does not work with Python 3. In my case that was exactly the problem. My default Python command was pointing to version 3 instead of version 2.

You can check your current default python with:

```
which python
```

As I already had Python 2.7 installed, as soon as I ran:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Terminator started to work again.

Comment: I was also using python3

Comment: Same here. Thanks. But why does having 3.x as default break terminator? Is it written in python?

Comment: Perfect awnser!

Comment: Definitely not perfect. I don't want to mess up my whole environment by setting a different default python version. RawCode below has a better answer.

Answer (score 10):

@desveladisimo's answer will fix your issue but you won't be able to use Python 3 as your default version. In order to use Python3 as default and still have terminator working, you can configure Terminator to use Python2 with the following steps:-

Edit the /usr/bin/terminator

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/terminator
```

and change the first line (shebang)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

> Source - https://askubuntu.com/a/1156909

Comment: This is the best answer since Terminator is dependent on a specific version of Python.  Allows me to have Python3 for generic work while keeping Terminator happy with a specific version.

Comment: This is supposed to be a more correct answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

I was working under the assumption that purging terminator would delete its config. This was not the case. I had to manually delete it (be aware that your profile *will* be lost):

```
$ rm ~/.config/terminator/* -rfv
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/634148/how-to-reset-terminator-terminal-emulator-configuration)

Part of the error message are warning that can be ignored, namely:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
ConfigBase::load: Unable to open /home/philipp/.config/terminator/config ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/philipp/.config/terminator/config')
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'
```

This will always show as pointed on on [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1518065)

Deleting the config makes terminator start again.

Comment: Good to see that you got it working again. I would have thought that the `Floating point exception (core dumped)` would be a bug.

Comment: @Jos I guess it had to do with a config issue, yet since I deleted it right away I cannot compare to find the real cause :/

Comment: Also, I thought `purge` *did* remove all configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by this part of my config file:

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_image = None
    foreground_color = "#ffffff"
    scrollback_lines = 5000
    use_custom_command = True
```

`use_custom_command` is `True`, but `custom_command` property is not set. Changing `use_custom_command` to `False` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggested to change the default python version system wide to make terminator running. There is another possibility. Open the terminator script

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/terminator
```

and change the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Now every time terminator starts up it will use python2.7 instead of your default python version 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to upgrade to the latest version, for which instructions are provided on the following page, after the project moved to GitHub:

https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have set infinite scrollback and the Teminator app is having problems with that. Remove the scrollback from [default] and it may help